# How to create changeable onclick function relying on a a variable passed from while loop php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

I have a list of items generated from while loop PHP. Below each one of them there is another list generated from while loop as well and should be appeared only when the user click on it. In jquery I use onclick function but I can not make togglenave function and navigation_lists ID changeable according to the ID passed from while loop. So when I click on any of the parent items, what is appeared is just while loop of the first row. I am not good at all with javascript or jquery and for this reason I need your help

**PHP**

```
$cities=mysql_query("select * from cities");
while($city = mysql_fetch_array($cities))
    {
    $idn = $city['id'];
    $cityn = $city['city'];
    echo '<li onclick="toggleclas'.$idn.'()><a onclick="toggleNave'.$idn.'(); return false;">'.$cityn.'<i id="myDIV'.$idn.'" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>';
    echo '<ul id="navigation_lists'.$idn.'" role="navigation">';
    $categories = mysql_query("select * from categories);
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
        {
        $city1 = $category ['city'];
        $category1 = $category ['category'];
        $catnames = mysql_query("select * from type");
        echo '<li class="submenu">';
            echo '<a href="#">';
                 echo $category1 ;
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        }
     echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
  }
```

**Javascript**

```
var originalNavClasse;

function toggleNave2()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_lists2');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasse === undefined) {
        originalNavClasse = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasse : originalNavClasse + ' expanded';
}

function toggleclas2()
{
    $('#myDIV2').toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-caret-up");
}

var originalNavClasse;

function toggleNave3()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_lists3');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasse === undefined) {
        originalNavClasse = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasse : originalNavClasse + ' expanded';
}

function toggleclas3()
{
    $('#myDIV3').toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-caret-up");
}

var originalNavClasse;

function toggleNave4()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_lists4');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasse === undefined) {
        originalNavClasse = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasse : 
originalNavClasse + ' expanded';
}

function toggleclas4()
{
    $('#myDIV4').toggleClass("fa-caret-down fa-caret-up");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use class instead of id, that is why only the first one works.

```
<?php
# Stop using mysql_* functions, they are removed in PHP7. Use PDO or mysqli_*
# Secondly you want to move all these out of loops, otherwise you are calling
# the database on each iteration and sub-iteration. Since they don't depend on
# WHERE clauses, you only need to call them once
$cities     = mysql_query("select * from cities");
$categories = mysql_query("select * from categories");
$catnames   = mysql_query("select * from type");

while($city = mysql_fetch_array($cities)):
    $idn = $city['id'];
    $cityn = $city['city']; ?>

    <li>
        <!-- USE A CLASS HERE -->
        <a href="" class="main-button"><?php echo $cityn ?><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <!-- USE A CLASS HERE -->
        <ul class="navigation-lists" role="navigation">
            <?php while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($categories)):
                $city1 = $category ['city'];
                $category1 = $category ['category']; ?>
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="#"><?php echo $category1 ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile ?>
        </ul>
    </li>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

I am going to use jQuery because it's easy and a great library:

```
<!-- YOU NEED TO ADD THE LIBRARY BEFORE USING JQUERY -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
// Document ready listener
$(function(){
    // Listen for <a> click
    $('.main-button').on('click',function(e){
        // Stop the <a> from reloading the page
        e.preventDefault();
        // Fetch the navigation list based on the current selection
        var elem = $(this).next('.navigation-lists');
        // This will run the toggleClas functions you have by searching children
        // for the <i> tag and acting on it
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-caret-down');
        // Continue to work with the js here based on what you have in your script...
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way to edit the javascript code I shared in my question here above to make it work? BTW I tried your answer and still is not working. Thanks

Comment: Yeah should be able to integrate back in there, I just don't know what it's trying to do. for instance, what is `/expanded/.test(classes)` doing? Matching?

Comment: This is apart of drop down menu I use for mobile version which includes many sections ... Some of them should have another sub menu

Comment: Also, this statement `(originalNavClasse === undefined) {`, how can it be undefined if you set it above with `var originalNavClasse;`?

Comment: Also can you give a small example html snippet? It's hard to do javascript without seeing what the output is.

Comment: I will make it more clear for you. I have function toggleNave2, function toggleNave3, function toggleNave4 & function toggleNave5. And I execute the same javascript to all of them. How can I make the number of the function auto increment without writing the same code again

Comment: I will edit my code right now both html and javascript to see what I mean

Comment: By the way I've add a unique id $idn to each function name and it works but the only problem i have right now is writing the same javascript code many times instead of being repeated automatically making just the change in the number coming after the function name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168590/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-mido).